# Calculating fluxes in local Lax-Friedrichs FVM for shallow water problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, finite-volume-method

so I have a more programming and some applied maths background, but absolutely none in FVM or Fluid dynamics. I have to implement a solver using the local Lax-Friedrichs method, and so far kinda-so-good. But I got stuck in calculating the fluxes (F and G) in the following Finite Volume solver equation:

$$U_{i,j}^{n+1} - U_{i,j}^{n} = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}[F(u(x_{i+\frac{1}{2}},y,t))-F(u(x_{i-\frac{1}{2}},y,t))] + \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta y}[G(u(x,y_{i+\frac{1}{2}},t))-G((x,y_{i-\frac{1}{2}},t))]$$

The original differential Equation(which neglects a lot of forces) is as follows:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}h \\ hu \\ hv \end{bmatrix}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\begin{bmatrix}hu \\ hu^2 + 0.5gh^2 \\ huv \end{bmatrix}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\begin{bmatrix}hv \\ huv \\ hv^2 + 0.5gh^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -\frac{\partial (ghb)}{\partial x}\\ -\frac{\partial (ghb)}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}$$

Where: 
b is the depth at a point
h is the distance from the bottom of the body of water till the lowest point of a "wave"
hu is one wavelength of a propagating wave\

I hope I explained it thoroughly, to sum up, I sort off understand what needs to be done, but I am having troubles on how to calculate the values of the fluxes to be used in the FV formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the PDE as follows:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(U)+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(U) = 0$$
where
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}h \\ hu \\ hv \end{bmatrix},\quad
F(U) = \begin{bmatrix}hu \\ hu^2 + 0.5gh^2 + ghb \\ huv \end{bmatrix}, \quad
G(U) = \begin{bmatrix}hv \\ huv \\ hv^2 + 0.5gh^2 + ghb\end{bmatrix} .
$$
The 2D local Lax-Friedrichs (LLF) method can be derived from these expressions, see [this document](http://mhdsim.uni-koeln.de/assets/part2.pdf). The scheme reads
$$
U_{i,j}^{n+1} = U_{i,j}^n - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}\left(F_{i+\frac12,j}^n - F_{i-\frac12,j}^n\right) - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta y}\left(G_{i,j+\frac12}^n - G_{i,j-\frac12}^n\right)
$$
where the LLF numerical fluxes are given in the linked document p. 33.

Comment: Thanks, Very helpful, Follow up question: If the flux is a scalar value(which I think it is), how to we calculate it given that the F(U) and G(U) functions have 3 components to it? Using the formulae in the referenced document on page 33.

Comment: @Ian Answer edited! I believe that unknowns $U$ and fluxes $F$ are also assumed vectors, since they introduce the signal speed $\lambda^x_{i+1/2, j}$ in $x$-direction as *the maximum Eigenvalues of the flux Jacobian* $\partial F/\partial U$. Differentiating the flux vector $F$ w.r.t. to the vector $U$ gives a Jacobian matrix, of which we can compute the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks, It is starting to fall into place! If I suddenly develop an extra question to this, should i edit my original question,or post new?
But a short question otherwise, if the fluxes F and G are vectors, then the 1st component is used to update h, the second to update hu, and the last to update hv?