# Using Runge Kutta in local lax friedrichs fvm for shallow water problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, runge-kutta-methods, finite-volume-method

This question is working on the same problem but using a new concept as mentioned [here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3744898/418542).

Now I am trying to expand this concept using the [Runge kutta (RK4):](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). Now the original PDE is as follows:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\begin{bmatrix}h \\ hu \\ hv \end{bmatrix}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\begin{bmatrix}hu \\ hu^2 + 0.5gh^2 \\ huv \end{bmatrix}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\begin{bmatrix}hv \\ huv \\ hv^2 + 0.5gh^2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -\frac{\partial (ghb)}{\partial x}\\ -\frac{\partial (ghb)}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}$$

But lets just consider it in the form $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U+ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(U)+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(U) = 0$$

Now, under the current numerical Scheme, each of the varibles h,hu and hv is updated using the following:$$U_{i,j}^{n+1} = U_{i,j}^n - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}\left(F_{i+\frac12,j}^n - F_{i-\frac12,j}^n\right) - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta y}\left(G_{i,j+\frac12}^n - G_{i,j-\frac12}^n\right)$$

Where F and G are fluxes calculated by the following: (Simulary for G, but in the other direction), more [here around page 33:](http://mhdsim.uni-koeln.de/assets/part2.pdf)
$$F_{i+0.5j}^{n,LLF} = 0.5(f(u_{i,j}^n)+f(u_{i+1,j}^n)))-\frac{\lambda^x_{i+0.5j,max}}{2}(u_{i+1,j}^n-u_{i,j}^n)$$

Now, if I want to use RK4 in this problem, I understand that the above equation needs to be changed to the new scheme.

I assume the following new update to be true:
$$U_{i,j}^{n+1} = U_{i,j}^n - \frac{\Delta t}{6}\left(k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4\right)$$

Now this is where I am not sure anymore, I think I need to define $k_1...k_4$, in terms of the fluxes and I am also missing $\Delta x$ in the formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to define the spatial operator as right hand side $R$ with

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = R(t,U(\boldsymbol{x},t)) ~~~ \text{where}~~~ \boldsymbol{x}=[x,y]^T,$$
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = \frac{\left(F_{i+\frac12,j}^n - F_{i-\frac12,j}^n\right)}{ \Delta x } - \frac{\left(G_{i,j+\frac12}^n - G_{i,j-\frac12}^n\right)}{\Delta y }$$

Then the $k_i$ values are simply defined as subsecant procedure via

$$ k_1 =  R(t_n, U_n), $$
$$ k_2 =  R\left(t_n + \frac{\Delta t}{2}, U_n +    \Delta t \frac{k_1}{2}\right), $$
$$ k_3 =  R\left(t_n + \frac{\Delta t}{2}, U_n +  \Delta t \frac{k_2}{2}\right), $$
$$ k_4 =  R\left(t_n + \Delta t, U_n +  \Delta t k_3\right), $$

with the final step

$$U_{n+1} = U_n - \frac{\Delta t}{6}\left(k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4\right).$$

Done!

You simply have to use the previous intermediate (temporal) solutions $k_{i}$ for the calculation of the next  $k_{i+1}$ variables.

Comment: ahh I think I understand, so I simply evaluate $k_1=\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = \Delta x \left(F_{i+\frac12,j}^n - F_{i-\frac12,j}^n\right) - \Delta y \left(G_{i,j+\frac12}^n - G_{i,j-\frac12}^n\right)$, then the other $k_{i+1}$ varibles are very easy to evaluate...

Comment: Yes it is straight forward! Use $\tilde{U}_{n+1/2}=U_n+\Delta t \frac{k_1}{2} $ as next input for $R$.

Comment: Note that i have corrected a small typo. You have to divide by $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$.

Comment: so, the function $ \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\Delta x } \left(F_{i+\frac12,j}^n - F_{i-\frac12,j}^n\right) - \frac{1}{\Delta y }\left(G_{i,j+\frac12}^n - G_{i,j-\frac12}^n\right)$ is not dependant on time, but only current values. I assume this will just simplify the $k_i$ calculations? *EDIT: I see now you possibly already answered this 2 comments ago. But cant hurt to just be extra sure.

Comment: Yes the function is time independent.